# Compute rolling z-score in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a open source function to compute moving z-score like https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.toolkits.anomaly_detection.moving_zscore.create.html. I have access to pandas rolling_std for computing std, but want to see if it can be extended to compute rolling z scores.

Comment: Yeah, use `rolling.apply`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`rolling.apply` with a custom function is significantly slower than using builtin rolling functions (such as mean and std). Therefore, compute the rolling z-score from the rolling mean and rolling std:

```
def zscore(x, window):
    r = x.rolling(window=window)
    m = r.mean().shift(1)
    s = r.std(ddof=0).shift(1)
    z = (x-m)/s
    return z
```

According to the definition given on [this page](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.toolkits.anomaly_detection.moving_zscore.create.html) the rolling z-score depends on the rolling mean and std just prior to the current point. The `shift(1)` is used above to achieve this effect.

---

Below, even for a small Series (of length 100), `zscore` is over 5x faster than using `rolling.apply`. Since `rolling.apply(zscore_func)` calls `zscore_func` once for each rolling window in essentially a Python loop, the advantage of using the Cythonized `r.mean()` and `r.std()` functions becomes even more apparent as the size of the loop increases.
Thus, as the length of the Series increases, the speed advantage of `zscore` increases.

```
In [58]: %timeit zscore(x, N)
1000 loops, best of 3: 903 µs per loop

In [59]: %timeit zscore_using_apply(x, N)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.84 ms per loop
```

This is the setup used for the benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)

def zscore(x, window):
    r = x.rolling(window=window)
    m = r.mean().shift(1)
    s = r.std(ddof=0).shift(1)
    z = (x-m)/s
    return z


def zscore_using_apply(x, window):
    def zscore_func(x):
        return (x[-1] - x[:-1].mean())/x[:-1].std(ddof=0)
    return x.rolling(window=window+1).apply(zscore_func)

N = 5
x = pd.Series((np.random.random(100) - 0.5).cumsum())

result = zscore(x, N)
alt = zscore_using_apply(x, N)

assert not ((result - alt).abs() > 1e-8).any()
```

Comment: thanks @unubtu, great answer! I was initially interested in rolling apply because I was doing a pandas groupby operation and then doing zolling z score calculation

Comment: Thank you for coding the shift (-:

Comment: do we need to use the `shift()` function here, because `rolling()` function is gonna handle it well with the given period of time. isn't it??

Comment: I think you're right @id101112 - no `shift()` is needed, as you've "seen" the data at time `window`, so it is reasonable to compute the z_score to that value.

Comment: The central limit theorem states that for a sample to be normally distributed the no. of samples to be taken is 30. However I see that you are taking a window size of 5 and similarly I have taken a window size of 15 for anomaly detection in stock prices and results are really good. Can you please explain the statistical significance or am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 12):

You should use native functions of pandas:

```
 # Compute rolling zscore for column ="COL" and window=window
 col_mean = df["COL"].rolling(window=window).mean()
 col_std = df["COL"].rolling(window=window).std()

 df["COL_ZSCORE"] = (df["COL"] - col_mean)/col_std
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def zscore(arr, window):
    x = arr.rolling(window = 1).mean()
    u = arr.rolling(window = window).mean()
    o = arr.rolling(window = window).std()

    return (x-u)/o

df['zscore'] = zscore(df['value'],window)
```

Comment: Hello Bobby! Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you read [how to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), this should help you write an effective answer that is understandable, complete, and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have a data frame called data, which looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCBqb.jpg)

then you run the following code,

data_zscore=data.apply(lambda x: (x-x.expanding().mean())/x.expanding().std())

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obhIK.jpg)
Please note that the first row will always have NaN values as it doesn't have a standard deviation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in a single line of code. Given that `s` is the input series and `wlen` is the window length:

```
zscore = s.sub(s.rolling(wlen).mean()).div(s.rolling(wlen).std())
```

If you need to shift the mean and std it can still be done:

```
zscore = s.sub(s.rolling(wlen).mean().shift()).div(s.rolling(wlen).std().shift())
```