# Compute rolling z-score over Pandas Series with Scipy gives error

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have generic DataFrame with float numbers and no NaN's or Inf's. I want to compute the rolling Z-Score over the column `Values` and took help of [Scipy's z-score](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html).

This works, but it's computing Z-Score over the whole column i.e. not rolling:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
df['Z-Score'] = zscore(df['Values'])
```

This is what I want to do but it's giving me an error:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
window_size = 5
df['Z-Score'] = df['Values'].rolling(window_size).apply(lambda s: zscore(s))
```

I get `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`.

I've searched over and over but can't find what the issue is. What am I doing wrong?

---

I know I can implement the `zscore` function myself which is more performant but I'd rather use a library.

Comment: @GoldenLion I'm not sure if I understand your comment completely. Would you mind posting an answer with the suggested code changes?

Comment: what is your data?   z-scores are produced from variance, so the first row will not have a z-score

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' `Rolling.apply()` expects a function that outputs a scalar. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html#pandas-core-window-rolling-rolling-apply):

> func: function
> Must produce a single value from an ndarray input if raw=True or a single value from a Series if raw=False. Can also accept a Numba JIT function with engine='numba' specified.

You need to rethink what you really want this computation to do. What exactly is the Z-score of a window of your data? Do you want an average Z-score? Do you want a Z-score based on the distribution of your entire data or just the window? As it is, I can't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is legitimate reason for having a rolling Z-score as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164950/compute-rolling-z-score-in-pandas-dataframe 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596912/rolling-z-score-applied-to-pandas-dataframe.
The only difference is that instead of implementing my own manual Z-score function, I'd like to use Scipy's Z-score function instead. Is there any way that's possible?